# dataProvider with @Before testng

Tags: selenium, testing, jenkins, testng

I am working with one TestNG script with SauceLab and Jenkins. I stuck with one problem. When I run my project from Jenkins I will select browsers from there, so I can use it with "dataProvider", but dataProvider is only working with @Test annotations, I want to use dataProvider with @before.

Steps:

1. @Before will initialize the driver (Webdriver) object.
2. @Test with execute first test case with driver object.
3. @Test (2nd) with execute second test case with same driver object.

```java
public class test
{
    Webdriver driver;

    // Over here I want to use @Before
    @Test(dataProvider = "dynamicParameters", priority = 0, alwaysRun = true)
    public void init(String browser, String version, String os, Method method) throws Exception
    {
        System.out.println("Init Method");
        String BASE_URL = System.getProperty("baseUrl");
        PCRUtils pcrUtils = new PCRUtils();
        driver = pcrUtils.createDriver(browser, version, os, method.getName());

        driver.get(BASE_URL);
        driver.manage().window().maximize();
        Thread.sleep(50000);
     }

     @Test(priority = 1)
     public void verifyTitle() throws InterruptedException
     {
        AccountPage accountPage = new AccountPage();
        accountPage.verifyTitle(driver);
     }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

TestNG "@before" methods cannot be used directly with a [`@DataProvider`](http://testng.org/javadocs/org/testng/annotations/DataProvider.html).

A [`@BeforeMethod`](http://testng.org/javadocs/org/testng/annotations/BeforeMethod.html) can access the list of parameters ([TestNG - 5.18.1 - Native dependency injection](http://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html#native-dependency-injection)):

> Any @BeforeMethod can declare a parameter of type `Object[]`. This parameter will receive the list of parameters that are about to be fed to the upcoming test method, which could be either injected by TestNG, such as `java.lang.reflect.Method` or come from a `@DataProvider`

But a `@BeforeMethod` "will be run before each test method" and what you want is something more like [`@BeforeClass`](http://testng.org/javadocs/org/testng/annotations/BeforeClass.html) which "will be run before the first test method in the current class is invoked" ([TestNG - 2 - Annotations](http://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html#annotations)). Unfortunately `@BeforeClass` cannot access the list of parameters via TestNG's native dependency injection like a `@BeforeMethod` can.

A [`@Factory`](http://testng.org/javadocs/org/testng/annotations/Factory.html) however can be used to accomplish the initial, data-driven setup with a `@DataProvider`. e.g.:

```java
public class test
{
    WebDriver driver;

    @Factory(dataProvider = "dynamicParameters")
    public test(String browser, String version, String os, Method method) throws Exception
    {
        System.out.println("Init Method");
        String BASE_URL = System.getProperty("baseUrl");
        PCRUtils pcrUtils = new PCRUtils();
        driver = pcrUtils.createDriver(browser, version, os, method.getName());

        driver.get(BASE_URL);
        driver.manage().window().maximize();
        Thread.sleep(50000);
    }

    @Test(priority = 1)
    public void verifyTitle() throws InterruptedException
    {
        AccountPage accountPage = new AccountPage();
        accountPage.verifyTitle(driver);
    }

    @Test(priority = 2)
    public void verifySomethingElse() throws InterruptedException
    {
        // execute second test case with same driver object.
    }
}
```

See [TestNG - 5.8 - Factories](http://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html#factories) for more details.